# Java parse Data string Android

Tags: android, simpledateformat

i'm trying to parse a String using Java SimpleDateFormat.
My String is :

> 2/23/2013 10:12:52 PM

As oracle Javadoc, i wrote the following patter:

> MM/dd/yyyy KK:mm:ss a

IMHO i'm not sure about the PM(aa), i tryied also only 'a' or 'aaa' but i always get a ParseException. The funny thing is that when running it on a test project as a java application, it works:

When i run it in an android project, it doesn't work:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy KK:mm:ss a");
    try {
        Date data = formatter.parse("2/23/2013 10:12:52 PM");
        System.out.println(data);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Like I said below, your code is working just fine in a new Android Activity Project. I tried it myself and logcat reported: "Sat Feb 23 22:12:52 GMT+00:00 2013" which is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I didn't said that my "2/23/2013 10:12:52 PM" string is composed by the Json library...and maybe it is not build as an entire string, but char by char, and this might be a problem for the SimpleDateFormat. I tried to launch the following code:

```
String data1 = "2/23/2013 10:12:52 PM"; //a string built by Json parser
String data2 = "2/23/2013 10:12:52 PM"; //created by hand as new String
System.out.println(data2.equals(data1));
```

It returns false!

Solution:

```
String data1 = "2/23/2013 10:12:52 PM"; //a string built by Json parser
String data2 = "2/23/2013 10:12:52 PM"; //created by hand as new String
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append(data1);
System.out.println(data2.equals(data1));
```

Now it returns true!

Answer (score 0):

> when running it on a test project as a java application, it works:

Make sure you imported the correct libraries in your android project.

Comment: Sorry, but SimpleDateFormat is a standard Java class, it doesn't require an external library.

Answer (score 0):

If your format was "MM/...", your date would start with "02/23...".

Try with one "M" only.

Comment: Same for the day part, if you are going to have 2/1/2013 then put only one 'd'. Put two 'd' and 'M' if you'll have 02/01/2013

Comment: I ran his code in a plain new Android Activity Project and it works either way. 1 or 2 M's doesn't matter. The result is:  "Sat Feb 23 22:12:52 GMT+00:00 2013"

Comment: I tried with M and MM. In a simple java project, the date with single char like 2 is recognized also by the pattern with MM.
However, i did some test using M or MM but it doesn't works.